# Is it correct to use 'no continent'?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, is it correct to use 'no continent'? Or should I use 'no other continent'?

> There is no continent in the world as big as Asia.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.  In your example sentence the "other" is implied.  For example:

> There is no one (else) as nice as Marsha.

Of course Marsha herself is *as nice as* Marsha, but it would be a silly sentence if I were comparing Marsha to herself, rather than to everyone else in the world, so the "else" is optional in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. How about this sentence: there is no bird park in Southeast Asia as big as Jurong Bird Park?

Comment: @theinlwin  Is that from some textbook?  That's the third time I've read this example using Jurong Bird Park.

Comment: Yes, Andrew. That bird park is in Southeast Asia.  Is the  sentence acceptable?

Comment: @theinlwin  yes, I know it's in Singapore.  I've been there.  I was just curious if your example sentence is from some common textbook.   Anyway the sentence is grammatical.